# Passing index variable to function

Tags: angular

I am using a function (set_id) in a component as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
menus;
elementId;
  constructor(private api: ApiService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.api.getMenus().subscribe(res => {this.menus = res});
  }
  set_id(id){
    console.log(id)
  }
}
```

I want to record the 'id' when a user clicks on each button, button I am unsure how to get the id passed to the function assigned to the button.

**Here is what I have tried, but Angular cannot find the 'id' parameter in set_id(id) when I write it this way:**

```
<div *ngFor="let menu of menus; index as id">
    <ul>
        <li><button (click)="set_id(id)">{{menu['lesson-name']}}</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I access id from the index and pass it to the set_id function as the id parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get index you need to get it like `let id = index`

```
<div *ngFor="let menu of menus; let id = index">
    <ul>
        <li><button (click)="set_id(id)">{{menu['lesson-name']}}</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```